# Recover all databases to a new server

Tags: sql-server, restore

I need to copy an entire SQL Server instance, with all databases from one server to another server in my test lab.

I am aware that this can be done the "cold way", by stopping/pausing the databases and copying the database files to new location and attaching them.

Is it however possible to do it the "hot way," using the full and diff backup files?

Comment: Are you by chance using Vmware, Vmotion will *almost* do what you are asking. Or else, you have Logshipping, mirroring and Availability groups for your help

Comment: Not using Wmvare. 
in addition to this I feel a question about backups is jsutified. 
Many of regular tools I have seen for doing day to day backups use "hot-mode" . 
But is it not desirable to have day to day backups that easily can be restored on a new server in case disk-failure and such on the working server.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) --> **[`Start-DbaMigration`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Start-DbaMigration)**  to do the entire server migration/copy - (choose backup/restore method) including jobs, logins, user objects created in system dbs, etc

> ```
> Start-DbaMigration
>     [[-Source] <DbaInstanceParameter>] [[-Destination] <DbaInstanceParameter[]>]
>     [-DetachAttach] [-Reattach] [-BackupRestore] [[-SharedPath] <String>]
>     [-WithReplace] [-NoRecovery] [-SetSourceReadOnly] [-ReuseSourceFolderStructure]
>     [-IncludeSupportDbs]
>     [[-SourceSqlCredential] <PSCredential>]
>     [[-DestinationSqlCredential] <PSCredential>]
>     [[-Exclude] <String[]>] [-DisableJobsOnDestination] [-DisableJobsOnSource]
>     [-ExcludeSaRename] [-UseLastBackup] [-Continue] [-Force] [-EnableException]
>     [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check out dbatools  pretty sure they've got some scripts to handle this.